# Match and replace one *MSWORD* regex pattern with another

Tags: regex, replace, ms-word

I have a MSWord file that has hundreds of entries organized like this:

`CAPS WORD OR WORDS` `^t` `lowercase word or words` `^n`

I'd like to match these patterns and replace the `^t` with `^n`. So far, I have this to match them: `<[A-Z][A-Z]{2,}>^t<[a-z][a-z]{2,}>`

How can I maintain those matched words (assuming they're not all the same word) and replace the matched `^t` with an `^n`?

Edit: I've provided a complete example below. Change:

`ACH BLEIB BEI UNS` `^t` `hymn introduction` `^n`

To

`ACH BLEIB BEI UNS` `^n` `hymn introduction` `^n`

(the first group will always be 1 or more uppercase words; the second group will always be 1 or more lowercase words; there will always be a `^t` separating them and a `^n` at the end

Comment: Why don't you simply replace `\t` with `\n`?

Comment: Replacing `\t` would replace all tabs in the file with `\n`, which messes up other lines.

Comment: Maybe providing us with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be best then?

Comment: Your pattern was really confusing to me until I looked up the bizarre way MS Word does regular expressions. Leave it to Microsoft to reinvent the wheel every chance they get.

Comment: CT: see above. Austin: yeah but that's what I have to work with...I'm sure people will see what I mean if they look it up too.

Comment: `(<[A-Z][A-Z]{2,}>)^t(<[a-z][a-z]{2,}>)` -> `\1^n\2^n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use capturing groups:

```
(<[A-Z][A-Z]{2,}>)^t(<[a-z][a-z]{2,}>)
^                ^  ^                ^
```

Those pairs of unescaped parentheses will create *numbered capturing groups*. Now, the values captured can be accessed from the replacement pattern with the `\n` where `n` is the number of the capturing group starting with `1`.

So, replace the above with `\1^n\2`.